# How do I get x2go out of fullscreen mode when ctrl-alt-F stops working?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, fullscreen, remote-access, xfce

Anybody know any fix besides killing the x2goclient, killing the x2goserver, ctrl-alt-f, ctrl-click top-right corner of screen?
None of these fixes actually gets it out of full screen mode, so the question remains un-answered.

In my research:
I found a bug report that was closed without fixing that describes my situation exactly: [x2goclient: Unable to exit full screen mode.](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=858964)
I saw that it was closed as not a bug. I very much disagree, this is a bug.

I started a new bug report, almost identical, which I did not yet send. I include it here as a detailed explanation of what went wrong.

Package: x2goclient
Version: 4.1.2.2

Dear Maintainer,

* What led up to the situation?

Running in full screen mode, loss of connectivity between client and server.

* What exactly did you do (or not do) that was effective (or
ineffective)?

Had to switch to ctrl-alt-f1 terminal prompt, log in, and kill the x2go
client process. I also ctrl-clicked in the top-right hand corner of the screen. I also pressed ctrl-alt-f.

* What was the outcome of this action?

The process was hard terminated by the kill approach. ctrl-click in the top-right minimized the screen which was helpful in getting back to the host without killing the client, but did not get me out of full screen such that I could resize the screen again. ctrl-alt-f had no effect at all.

* What outcome did you expect instead?

ctrl-alt-f should get out of full screen and allow resizing. ctrl-click top-right should do the same.

Running xubuntu 20.04. Tried on multiple machines, and this session is no longer able to exit full screen. This may be a server bug, not a client bug.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I discovered that it was a classic stuck key issue. Ctrl-alt-F and ctrl-right click both stopped working because the server seemed to be ignoring the ctrl key.

To fix it, I pressed and released all of my modifier keys, one at a time:
left-ctrl, left-alt, left-shift, right-shift, instert, scroll lock, num-lock, caps-lock...

Then I was able to use ctrl-alt-F to toggle fullscreen as usual.

I'm not going to submit the bug report, as I'm sure they will blame it on the OS or something and won't be willing to put in a fix despite the problem manifesting as a very-painful x2go bug.